# Fraction of painted cubes of a 4x4 cube

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

If we make up a $4\times 4$ cube by $1/n \times 1/n \times 1/n$ cubes and paint the outside of the cube, am I correct in saying that the fraction of painted cubes is given by $\frac{64n^3 - [n(4-\frac{2}{n})]^3}{64n^3} = \frac{64n^3 - 8(2n-1)^3}{64n^3} = 1 - \frac{1}{8}(2-\frac{1}{n})^3$ ?As there are a total of $64n^3$ small cubes, of which those that aren't painted are those on the inner cube which is covered by the outer layer, which has dimensions $(4-2/n)\times(4-2/n)\times(4-2/n)$, and so we can fit $[n(4-\frac{2}{n})]^3$ many small cubes in this inner cube. The result seems to give the correct result as $n\to\infty$, but unsure for general $n$.

Comment: Are "painted cubes" cubes with at least one painted side?

Comment: This might be helpful. I believe the sequence that you gave, on OEIS there is a sequence and corresponding explanation for each of the  [numerators](https://oeis.org/A154105) and [denominators](https://oeis.org/A016743). This should help find the answer since you are concerned about a fraction.